# AWS Cloudformation change set is not adding tags to the resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

There is an existing cloudformation stack (for ec2, cloudfront creation) and I want to add tags to the resources. When I am trying to create a change set for the stack, it says no changes detected.

Can you please help here as I am not able to understand why its happening ?

Comment: I googled your question and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088948/is-it-possible-to-just-add-tags-to-cloudformation-stack-after-it-is-created), which says just adding tags isn't enough to get CF to make the change.

Comment: @Tim that post says it will do the update. My issue is the change set is not detecting the tags added in the cloudformation script and change set is not getting created

Comment: Good spotting. I wonder if it's a bug that a tag change isn't enough to trigger updates? What happens if you make another small change, are the tags applied?

Comment: @Tim did you tried this adding tags on cloudformation stack and got same error like mine? When I am doing the changes, tags are not getting added at all. However if you try to add tags via Cloudformation GUI, it adds those tags. Really wonder what is going on ie why cloudformation is not adding tags via cloudformation script update

Comment: I haven't done any CloudFormation for a while so I've forgotten the details. My suggestion was to do another change that does trigger an update to the resource (not sure what, security group?) to see if tags are added when that other update deploys.

Comment: @Tim I triggered the change to update the stack. All changes are taking place except the tags. ie tags are not getting updated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the template, maybe the format isn't correct. You could also try creating a new stack to see if the tags are created.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you manage to find a workaround?

Comment: Looks like there is an issue about that problem: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/228#issuecomment-816194125